# Wordpress error functions.PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress website and a few days ago I added into the functions.php file this code:

I put it here:

```
//Register Navigations
 add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_menus' );
 function my_custom_menus() {
    register_nav_menus(
        array(
            'primary_nav' => __( 'Primary Navigation', 'Medico'),
            'top_nav' => __( 'Top Navigation', 'Medico')
          ) 
    );
}
```

HERE!!!
     /************* WOOCOMMERCE HOOKS AND CUSTOMIZATION ************/

I wanted to create a new custom menù, but the problem is that the website is crashed now and give me this error message:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/content/59/9450659/html/eyeclarity/wp-content/themes/medico/functions.php on line 177
```

I'm into the ftp server but I can't see this code in this functions.php.

Does anybody can help me please?

Comment: What's this? HERE!!! /********* WOOCOMMERCE HOOKS AND CUSTOMIZATION ********/

Comment: What is on your function.php `line:117` ?

Comment: And the code looks fine. But the error might be before or after these lines if you have mixed HTML then the line numbers that you see and WordPress sees might be different. Can you post the whole code of your function.php?

Comment: which line above is "line 177" ?

Comment: <?php

/********************* DEFINE MAIN PATHS ********************/

//error_reporting(-1);

define('Medico_PLUGINS',  get_template_directory() . '/plugins' ); // Shortcut to the /plugins/ directory



$adminPath  =  get_template_directory() . '/library/admin/';

$funcPath  =  get_template_directory() . '/library/functions/';

$incPath  =  get_template_directory() . '/library/includes/';



global $alc_options;

$alc_options = isset($_POST['options']) ? $_POST['options'] : get_option('alc_general_settings');

/************************************************************/

Comment: /*********** LOAD ALL REQUIRED SCRIPTS AND STYLES ***********/

function Medico_load_scripts()

{

 $alc_options = isset($_POST['options']) ? $_POST['options'] : get_option('alc_general_settings');

 if( $GLOBALS['pagenow'] != 'wp-login.php' && !is_admin())

 {

Comment: wp_enqueue_style('foundation-styles',  get_template_directory_uri().'/css/foundation.min.css');

  wp_enqueue_style('fgx-styles', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/fgx-foundation.css');

  wp_enqueue_style('main-styles', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/style.css');

Comment: It's too long I can't paste it

Comment: @user3548564 You don't have to paste the file in comment. Use pastebin.com or similar.

Comment: HERE:http://pastebin.com/M2mvBzDH